# errors compiling custom version of opencv-python in jetson arm64 nvidia-docker env

Tags: compiler-errors, customization, arm64, opencv, nvidia-docker, python

This link provided the original make bug i was facing.
I patched my version of opencv exactly as was said and now i have new bugs.
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17542

I am very new to C++. My main goal is to compile from source my custom opencv-python api into nvidia jetson nvidia docker image adapted for ARM64 processing architecture. The make -j6 compiled till 100 and gave new errors.

[image: compilation error log pt1]

[image: compilation error log pt2]

from what i understand, i needed to change the naming of the cv2 Ptr functions and parameters from /app/opencv-stitch/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:122:97cv after having fix xfeatures2d namespace conflict from pyopencv_generated_funcs.h and pyopencv_generated_types_content.h . this is all foreign to me and i don't know where to start navigating the c++ api structure to know where to fix these or if im having the correct intuition at all. help would be much appreciated!